# How to fix shortcuts after upgrading Macbook Pro to Monterey 12.5

Tags: macos

Have found that after upgrading Monterey I've suddenly had major problems with keyboard shortcuts.

The spotlight option Command+space simply scrolls down browser rather than bringing up Spotlight.

More annoying is Command+v for paste doesn't paste. Just a v.

I've looked at shortcuts in preferences and they are sound. tried resetting the SMC but that's not worked. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

These are symptoms of a non-functioning Command key. Can you try using your right-most Command key as well to test with `Command + space` and `Command + v`? If it works with the right Command button, then that means your left Command key somehow has broken, indicating keyboard failure, not uncommon with Intel Macs from around 2016-2020 sad to say, when the infamous "butterfly keyboard" was being distributed on Macs in those years.

But if the right Command key doesn't work, then there's probably something fishy going on with some setting somewhere. I found this [Command Key Not Working post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2081942), maybe it might help.

I found this [other site](https://www.howtoisolve.com/modifier-keys-not-working-on-mac/), saying if you go `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> click on Modifier Keys...`, make sure Command key has a function.

Comment: You can also test functionality using [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware)